# Which alternative is best English?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, mathematics

Are there any specific rules in English about how to refer to something that was introduced in the previous sentence? For example, compare these three sentences:

> Let X and Y be random variables with means u and v. If the random variables X and Y are independent ..
>
> Let X and Y be random variables with means u and v. If the random variables are independent ..
>
> Let X and Y be random variables with means u and v. If the variables are independent ..

Which alternative would most people use? I am concerned that someone might mistake the "variables" in the second sentence as a reference to the means, rather than the random variables.

Comment: Now you've given them names: .If X and Y are independent ...

Comment: All three sentences are perfectly clear and all three mean the exact same thing. But if you wanted to be super-duper really clear, you'd use exactly none of them. You'd say instead "If X and Y are". Done. By the way, english is the spin you put on the ball in billiards. This site is about English, a Germanic language.

Comment: Looks like @Edwin beats me to it by 7 seconds.

Comment: Only because I was less thorough.

Comment: Add these alternatives: "...If *these two* variables are independent..." and also "...If *these* variables are independent...".

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want to address in this case is brevity. Which one is the most concise yet retains as much meaning as possible?

Out of the three you have provided, the last one is the best. First, you state that X and Y are random variables. Now the reader knows what X and Y are so you can refer to them later. Second, you want to add that X and Y are independent. In doing this, you only need to refer back to the objects you're talking about, *not any of their properties* (i.e., that they're random) so as to keep it simple. The reader will still know X and Y are random because you stated it earlier.

Now, there is a better option here. In the first sentence, you have already stated that X and Y are variables. Following what I said above, you don't need to repeat this in the second sentence because *variables* is a property of *X and Y*. However, you can't just take it out and be done — you'll need to fill the space you left. So you simply replace *the variables* with *they*.

> Let X and Y be random variables with means u and v. If they are independent...

You ignore the properties *random* and *variables* and replace the subjects with a plural pronoun, *they*, because there is more than one subject.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we use the least informative expression which unambiguously refers to what we intend to refer to. Otherwise the sentence sounds off.

For example, one would never say "Xavier and Yvonne came home. Xavier and Yvonne cooked dinner." They would instead say "Xavier and Yvonne came home. They cooked dinner."

Similarly, after you say "Let X and Y be random variables with means u and v", the least informative expression you can use while still referring to X and Y is "they."

"If they are independent ..."

If you are worried about referential ambiguity with u and v, then go with "the variables" (it's clear enough).